# Extract specific columns based on target list ,

Tags: r

I have a data set comprising 1000 rows and 5000 columns, and I want to select specific columns  ("mydata"). The target columns are listed in the data frame "cols".
I've tried some of the examples posted here, but no success! Could anyone please suggest it to me?

```
 cols[1:5,]
 c("S100024810", "S100024905", "S100024920", "S100024923", "S100025437"
 )
 
 mydata[1:3,1:5]
 structure(list(S100024732 = c("1", "0", "1"), S100024733 = c("-", 
 "0", "0"), S100024803 = c("0", "0", "-"), S100024810 = c("1", 
 "1", "1"), S100024817 = c("-", "1", "-")), row.names = c(NA, 
 3L), class = "data.frame")
 
 mydata[,cols[cols %in% names(mydata)]]
 Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cols` appears to be a data frame with one column, so you need to reference for that column.

```
cols[cols[, 1] %in% names(mydata), 1]
# [1] "S100024810"
```

To prevent the result to be coerced to a vector if it's just one column (as it happens with your `cols` data frame), we need to do `drop=FALSE`.

```
mydata[, cols[cols[, 1] %in% names(mydata), 1], drop=FALSE]
#   S100024810
# 1          1
# 2          1
# 3          1
```

---

*Data:*

```
cols <- structure(list(V1 = c("S100024810", "S100024905", "S100024920", 
"S100024923", "S100025437")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

mydata <- structure(list(S100024732 = c("1", "0", "1"), S100024733 = c("-", 
"0", "0"), S100024803 = c("0", "0", "-"), S100024810 = c("1", 
"1", "1"), S100024817 = c("-", "1", "-")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you @Jay, actually, I am targetting column headers in 'mydata' based on the list in 'cols'. So list in 'cols' are column headers of 'my data' which are to be extracted

Comment: @Gopi So the expected result are those "headers" in `mydf` that match the headers in the "list" in `cols`?

Comment: Yes, it's work fine with your suggestion, thank you for your great help :)

Comment: @Gopi If `cols` really only has this one column, you might want to think about using a vector instead, which is easier to handle: `cols <- c("S100024810", "S100024905", "S100024920", "S100024923", "S100025437"); mydata[intersect(cols, names(mydata))]`